# Get BusinessHours in FullCalendar v 4.0

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

i'm updating from FullCalendar v3 to v4 and have a problem getting the businessHours from the clicked resource.

In v3 i'm getting the businessHours this way:

```
    select: function (eventClickInfo) {
        console.log(eventClickInfo.resource)
    }
```

Resource data:

```
...
businessHours: [
           start: XXX
           end: XXX
        ], [
           start: XXX
           end: XXX
        ]
       ...
```

But in V4 the resource Object got this structure:

```
_resource:
    businessHours:
        defs:
            203:
                allDay: false
                defId: "203"
                extendedProps:
                    end: {ms: 43200000, __edmType: "Edm.Time"}
                groupId: "_businessHours"
                hasEnd: true
                ...
            204:
                allDay: false
                defId: "204"
                extendedProps:
                    end: {ms: 72000000, __edmType: "Edm.Time"}
                groupId: "_businessHours"
                hasEnd: true
                ...
```

There is no start time and no way getting the business hours like `.getResource("XXX").getBusinessHours()`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's certainly true that the [v4 Resource Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-object) doesn't expose the businessHours property. I don't know if that's intentional or just an omission. I guess you could raise a [bug report or a feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/support) with the fullCalendar people if you wanted to get it included.

Comment: In the meantime, let's look at it another way: why do you need to get the businessHours information from the resource at the time when the user selects that resource? What are you planning to do with it? Perhaps there's another way to implement whatever functionality this relates to.

Comment: I need the business hours in a popup for validating inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use the businessHours values to check that the user's selection of start/end times is within the defined hours, then you don't actually need any custom code for that, or to retrieve the businessHours values at all.

If you set the option

```
selectConstraint: "businessHours"
```

in your fullCalendar setup, then the calendar code will prevent the user from choosing any time outside the business hours automatically. They cannot even attempt to select it.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEvoVN?&editable=true&editors=001

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint

Comment: Yes, but in my popup the user can select another time from a DateTimePicker.

Comment: how about removing that, then? Why do you need them to be able to change the time, if they already selected it from the calendar?

Comment: It's a customer wish.

Comment: ok well I suggest the fallback for that is that you validate the data again on the server-side when it's submitted (since you'll have to do that anyway to ensure integrity), and then if they have changed it to an invalid time, you can provide feedback that way. P.S. We don't always have to do everything the customer says, if they can be convinced that it's not a good idea, or told that it makes things difficult...